# How to call Alert onPress and pass some parameters in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, alert

Here I am calling on alert function onPress on text field .
On calling that function I am trying to open alert and on confirm I am calling another function.
But it gets hang if I am calling "showAlert1()" . This function is getting called many times
I have to call showAlert() function onPress and I have to send some value in it . And on confirmation OK button on Alert box I have to upload to server.

```js
showAlert1(code, name, version) {
  console.log("data alaert abc", code, name, version);
  Alert.alert(
    'Confirmation',
    'Are you sure you want to migrate this tariff',
    [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'Cancel',
      },
      { text: 'Proceed', onPress: () => this.confirmTariffMigration(code, name, version) },
    ]
  );
}

confirmTariffMigration = (code, name, version) => {
  console.log("hhhhdhhdhdhdhhdd", code, name, version);
  const objData = {
    addofferingActionCode: '',
    offeringCode: '',
    offeringName: ''
  }
  this.props.updateTariffMigration(objData)
}
```

```
<View style={{ marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5, marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1' }}>
  {
    tariffMigrationData.map((data, index) => {
      return (
        //  <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1(data)}>
        <View style={{ marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5, marginRight: 5 }} key={index}>
          <Card>
            <CardItem header style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', borderBottomColor: '#f1f1f1', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <View>
                  <RegularText text={`${data.offering.name}`} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }} />
                  <SmallText text={` ID ${data.offering.code}`} textColor="grey" />
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={{
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                borderRadius: 75, height: 25, paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingTop: 5
              }}>
                <SmallText text={'Proceed'} onPress={this.showAlert1(data.offering.code, data.offering.version, data.offering.name)} textColor='white' />
              </View>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
</View>
```

Comment: what is the error info?

Comment: nothing error .... this alert message is getting call while loading rendor function ..while it should only call on press.. so ui is getting hang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change :

```js
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1(data)}>
```

to

```js
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.showAlert1(data)}>
```

And

```js
showAlert1 (code,name,version) {  
    // code
}
```

To

```js
showAlert1 = (code,name,version) => {  
    // code
}
```

Comment: I did this <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.showAlert1(data)}>
but ,same ... please review my code and help me..

Comment: @AbhigyanGaurav I edited the answer. Please try something like that.

Comment: Hi Kishan..|
finally its woking.. thanks ..u r greate... actually I tried all this thing .. there was one { in my code extra because of this it was hqappening .. :)

Comment: @Kishan Bharda, could give some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure you have Imported "Alert" from 'react-native', not some other module.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMj8s.png

First of all, try changing this:

```html
<SmallText text={'Proceed'}  onPress={this.showAlert1(data.offering.code,data.offering.version,data.offering.name)} textColor='white' />
```

to:

```html
<SmallText text={'Proceed'}  onPress={() => this.showAlert1(data.offering.code,data.offering.version,data.offering.name)} textColor='white' />
```

Also try to change

```js
showAlert1 (code,name,version) {  
    #code
}
```

to

```js
showAlert1 = (code,name,version) => {  
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as the Kishan Bharda answer addition. when we met the problem, we should know why not just correct.

as for how to pass the function to the component props, you can read the official [blog](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html), and get more details

when we want to pass params to props, here are two ways:

```
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => this.showAlert1(data)}>
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1.bind(this,data)}>
```

when your do like your question

```
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={this.showAlert1(data)}>
```

it is not pass the funtion, it is called not a reference.

Comment: awsome Thanks a lot :)