# react-native-image-crop-picker camera or files not opening onpress

Tags: react-native

Hi everyone I'm using react-native-image-crop-picker to upload images. I have used the following code to do that

```
pickSingleWithCamera(cropping, mediaType = 'photo') {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: cropping,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      includeExif: true,
      mediaType,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: { uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime },
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single Image With Camera</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
```

when i used the code camera is not opening and the button is not responding onpress, so please tell me the solution

please once check my full code if i need to change anything please tell me

```
export default class AddPostScreen extends React.Component {

  pickSingleWithCamera(cropping, mediaType = 'photo') {
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
      cropping: cropping,
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      includeExif: true,
      mediaType,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: { uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime },
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  pickSingleBase64(cropit) {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      cropping: cropit,
      includeBase64: true,
      includeExif: true,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received base64 image');
      this.setState({
        image: { uri: `data:${image.mime};base64,` + image.data, width: image.width, height: image.height },
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  cleanupImages() {
    ImagePicker.clean().then(() => {
      console.log('removed tmp images from tmp directory');
    }).catch(e => {
      alert(e);
    });
  }

  cleanupSingleImage() {
    let image = this.state.image || (this.state.images && this.state.images.length ? this.state.images[0] : null);
    console.log('will cleanup image', image);

    ImagePicker.cleanSingle(image ? image.uri : null).then(() => {
      console.log(`removed tmp image ${image.uri} from tmp directory`);
    }).catch(e => {
      alert(e);
    })
  }

  cropLast() {
    if (!this.state.image) {
      return Alert.alert('No image', 'Before open cropping only, please select image');
    }

    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      path: this.state.image.uri,
      width: 200,
      height: 200
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received cropped image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: { uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime },
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
    });
  }

  pickSingle(cropit, circular = false, mediaType) {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      cropping: cropit,
      cropperCircleOverlay: circular,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 1000,
      compressImageMaxHeight: 1000,
      compressImageQuality: 1,
      compressVideoPreset: 'MediumQuality',
      includeExif: true,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log('received image', image);
      this.setState({
        image: { uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime },
        images: null
      });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
    });
  }

  pickMultiple() {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      waitAnimationEnd: false,
      includeExif: true,
      forceJpg: true,
    }).then(images => {
      this.setState({
        image: null,
        images: images.map(i => {
          console.log('received image', i);
          return { uri: i.path, width: i.width, height: i.height, mime: i.mime };
        })
      });
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }

  scaledHeight(oldW, oldH, newW) {
    return (oldH / oldW) * newW;
  }

  renderVideo(video) {
    console.log('rendering video');
    return (<View style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }}>
      <Video source={{ uri: video.uri, type: video.mime }}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0
        }}
        rate={1}
        paused={false}
        volume={1}
        muted={false}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
        onError={e => console.log(e)}
        onLoad={load => console.log(load)}
        repeat={true} />
    </View>);
  }

  renderImage(image) {
    return <Image style={{ width: 300, height: 300, resizeMode: 'contain' }} source={image} />
  }

  renderAsset(image) {
    if (image.mime && image.mime.toLowerCase().indexOf('video/') !== -1) {
      return this.renderVideo(image);
    }

    return this.renderImage(image);
  }




render(){
return(
<View>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single Image With Camera</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera(false, mediaType = 'video')} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single Video With Camera</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleWithCamera.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Camera With Cropping</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingle(false)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.cropLast()} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Crop Last Selected Image</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingleBase64(false)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single Returning Base64</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingle(true)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Cropping</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pickSingle(true, true)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Single With Circular Cropping</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pickMultiple.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Select Multiple</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.cleanupImages.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Cleanup All Images</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.cleanupSingleImage.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Cleanup Single Image</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

)
}
```

i am also used react-native NativeModules.ImageCropPicker instead of react-native-image-crop-picker.

Comment: you can see my answer in this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723037/hoe-to-call-alert-onpress-and-send-some-parameter-in-that-in-react-native/58723486#58723486), it may be the onPress pass method problem

Comment: did you add **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>** camera permission in manifest file?

Comment: I am looking for the photo upload, @bk7  your answer is related to my question 

can you please tell me the exact file location where i need to add the permission ,

Comment: I didn't find any file with manifest name can i add those permissions  in the above code

Comment: **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**, please follow **Post-install steps** in **https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker**

Comment: android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, for this file  i need to go to the production build => expo build:android  for that i am getting the error that's why i am asking can i give the permissions in project file instead of androidManifest file .

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time , Please once check this 
link https://snack.expo.io/@sivasankarchimata/authentic-fudge